# Parabolic regularity on a $C^\infty$ compact manifold

Tags: partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have a general parabolic PDE on a compact $C^\infty$ manifold $M$ $\textit{ie}$ a (the?) solution $u$ is a probability density
and satisfies the PDE in a weak sense (with $C^\infty_c$ test functions). For example take :

$$
\partial u_t = \Delta u + div(v u)
$$
with v smooth, boundary conditions (if there is a boundary) and initial conditions.

I would like to prove the strong maximum principle but for that I need regularity.
Do you know some references on this question ? Like Brezis' book "Functional Analysis,
Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" but for manifolds.

Thank you in advance !